# How to install perl(Unix::Syslog) on CentOS using yum?

Tags: perl, centos, repository, yum

I'm getting `perl(Unix::Syslog)` as a dependent package when I installing certain application.

```
perl(Unix::Syslog) is needed by
```

I tried installing it as `yum install 'perl(Unix::Syslog)'` but it give following result.

```
No package perl(Unix::Syslog) available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried to install it using `RPM` but it give lot more dependencies list.

So they best why for this is installing using `yum` but I cannot find a way to do this.

**Edit** : Actually I tried `yum install perl-Unix-Syslog` too but result is the same. May be I don't have the correct repository configured in my CentOS.

So I googled and found below as a fix but it didn't fix the issue.

```
yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try; `perl-Unix-Syslog`

```
yum info perl-unix-syslog
Available Packages
Name        : perl-Unix-Syslog
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.1
Release     : 3.el6
Size        : 28 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : Perl interface to the UNIX syslog(3) calls
URL         : http://search.cpan.org/dist/Unix-Syslog/
License     : Artistic 2.0
Description : This module provides an interface to the system logger syslogd(8) via
            : Perl's XSUBs. The implementation attempts to resemble the native libc-
            : functions of your system, so that anyone being familiar with syslog.h
            : should be able to use this module right away.
```

You can also find it via http://rpm.pbone.net

If you are missing the repo then add this to your `/etc/yum/repos.d/epel.repo`

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

You may also need to do; `yum clean all` before you retry the install to clear the cache and mirror list.

Comment: I have tied this but no luck. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: try doing `yum clean all` and then `yum install perl-Unix-Syslog` ive updated my answer with the repo full url block for your config file.

Comment: You saved my day! That fixed it!